# Vue Storefront Firebase SSR - Not working

Tags: firebase, vue-storefront

Trying to deploy to firebase using SSR but not having much luck. I've added "server-middleware" folder and "middleware.config.js". Though i'm not sure if this is correct.

I've previously deployed to firebase using the same method (plain nuxtjs project), however, it appears i'm missing something for vuestorefront. Any tips are much appreciated.

This is the example i followed for a previous project which worked - https://medium.com/@sirofjelly/deploying-a-nuxt-ssr-server-side-rendering-app-to-google-firebase-5d90117167db

[image: firebase.json predeploy]

[image]T

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)